# How to interact with web elements within a Plaid iFrame using Selenium Webdriver with Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, iframe, selenium-chromedriver

I am currently scripting an automation test suite for a client and trying to interact with a third party iFrame (Plaid) and select web elements within the iFrame. When I run the tests, the chromedriver just times out and is unable to find the iframe by id or xpath and the elements within it.
Note that this QA shard is also in Sandbox mode, so I was wondering if that might be affecting it from being located.

Attached is the code im using and the inspected source code screentshot below:

```
public void selectPlaidFrame(){
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(120));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(plaidHappyFrame));
    driver.switchTo().frame(plaidHappyFrame);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(plaidHappyFrameContinueButton));
    plaidHappyFrameContinueButton.click();
}
```

Please help
[Screenshot of source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNP0u.png)

```
@FindBy(id = "plaid-link-iframe-1")
private WebElement plaidHappyFrame;
@FindBy(id = "aut-button")
private WebElement plaidHappyFrameContinueButton;
```